# I use a radial gradient color as the border of a box, but the result looks weird

Tags: css, radial-gradients, border-image

I set a radial gradient color to the border-image-source of a box, and use initial values for border-image-slice, border-image-width and other border-image properties. But the result does not look like the radial gradient color at all.
The gradient color is as below:
[radial_gradient_color_as_fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdo4o.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .gradient-box {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            background: radial-gradient(closest-corner at center center, rgb(63, 135, 166) 0%, rgb(235, 248, 225) 50%, rgb(246, 157, 60) 100%);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="gradient-box"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

And the radial gradient color as border-image be like:
[radial_gradient_color_as_border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJQ2l.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .gradient-box {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            border: 50px solid;
            border-image: radial-gradient(closest-corner at center center, rgb(63, 135, 166) 0%, rgb(235, 248, 225) 50%, rgb(246, 157, 60) 100%) 1 / 1 / 0 stretch;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="gradient-box"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

What I expect the radial gradient color border is like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33AAB.png)

I changed the position of the radial gradient color, and it looks great. But when the position is center, it still looks wrong. I don't know why and want to know how to set those properties to make the radial gradient color looks good as border.
[radial_gradient_color_change_position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bZ5h.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .gradient-box {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            border: 50px solid;
            border-image: radial-gradient(at 25% 25%, rgb(63, 135, 166) 0%, rgb(235, 248, 225) 50%, rgb(246, 157, 60) 100%) 1 / 1 / 0 stretch;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="gradient-box"></div>
</body>

</html>
```